# How to subtract across tables and join only the row with the least difference using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL IN PROGRESS

```
    SELECT race_id, runner_id, end_time , end_lat, end_lng, (prev_lat-end_lng/prev_lng-runner_lng) as slope,
CASE WHEN slope > 0 THEN direction = 'POSITIVE'
WHEN slope < 0 THEN direction = 'NEGATIVE'
ELSE '0'
    FROM race_info_table ri
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 runner_id, runner_lat AS prev_lat, runner_lng AS prev_lng, occurred_at_10s, 
    datediff(second, occurred_at_10s,ri.end_time) as last_location 
    FROM runner_location_table rl
    ORDER BY datediff(second, occurred_at_10s,ri.end_time) ASC)
    ON ri.runner_id == rl.runner_id
```

PROBLEM WITH ABOVE QUERY - I specifically don't know how to join the race info data with the closest prev runner info time. The above query doesn't work because of the date diff part which fails because it doesn't know what ri.end_time is.

Question: How can I tell if a runner is running in the positive or negative direction of slope?

How to answer this question:

1. Calculate the difference between the times in the runner location table and the race_info table for each runner.
2. Find the shortest difference in times in the end_time and the occurred_at_10s timestamp.
3. Join the most recent 10 second previous location data of the runner from the runner_location_table to the race_info_table using runner_id.
4. Now the new table should have these columns: start_lng, start_lat, end_lng, end_lat, race_id, runner_id, end_time, start_time, runner_lat_100_prev, runner_lng_100_prev.

   5. Using runner_lat_100_prev, runner_lng_100_prev, end_lng, and end_lat, calculate the slope.
   6. Add a new column using case statements where if the slope is positive we have a new column called direction that says positive or negative if the slope is negative.

INPUT DATA

```
race_info_table
 - start_lng DOUBLE
 - start_lat DOUBLE
 - end_lng DOUBLE
 - end lat DOUBLE
 - race_id BIGINT
 - runner_id BIGINT
 - end_time TIMESTAMP
 - start_time TIMESTAMP

runner_location_table (recorded every 100 seconds)
 - runner_id BIGINT​, Unique identifier for a runner
 - runner_lat DOUBLE​, Latitude of runner location
 - runner_lng DOUBLE​, Longitude of runner location
 - occurred_at_10s TIMESTAMP​, UTC timestamp that increases in 100 second increments.
```

CODE TO CREATE TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE runner_locations_table (runner_id BIGINT,
runner_lat DOUBLE, 
runner_lng DOUBLE, 
occurred_at_10s TIMESTAMP);

CREATE TABLE race_info_table (runner_id BIGINT,
race_id BIGINT,
start_lat DOUBLE,
start_lng DOUBLE,
start_time TIMESTAMP,
end_lat DOUBLE,
end_lng DOUBLE,
end_time TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would really help.

Comment: SQL Server is not MySQL - tag the correct engine you are using. Based on the usage of timestamp datatype, you are not using sql server since that datatype has no relationship to date or time.

Comment: I am using MySQL5.6

Comment: Hi Eric, I apologize for the confusion as I am new to SQL. However, the question is now tagged properly as MySQL. The code I am working with is MySQL5.6 as I commented above and I am testing it in SQLFiddle where it seems to be working in the MySQL5.6 environment. Please explain why my code looks like SQL Server if you think I am still doing something incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

THIS QUESTION WAS ORIGINALLY TAGGED "sql-server".  THIS ANSWER IS ONLY FOR SQL SERVER.

I think you just want `outer apply`:

```
SELECT race_id, runner_id, end_time, end_lat, end_lng 
FROM race_info_table ri OUTER APPY
     (SELECT TOP 1 driver_id, driver_lat AS prev_lat, driver_lng AS prev_lng, occurred_at_10s, 
datediff(second, occurred_at_10s,ri.end_time) as last_location 
      FROM runner_location_table rl
      WHERE ri.runner_id = rl.runner_id
      ORDER BY datediff(second, occurred_at_10s, ri.end_time) ASC
     ) rl;
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you suggest OUTER APPLY and how that works in this case?

Comment: @pr338 . . . Because it is like a `LEFT JOIN` on a correlated subquery.  That appears to be what you are trying to do.

Comment: I added more details above, but this doesn't seem to work in MySQL 5.6. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks.